# xamarin forms - android widget update

Tags: android, xamarin, widget

Good day, i have a xamarin forms app, and i need to build a widget on an android platform.

I've implemented a widget from `SimpleWidget` and `HelloAppWidget`.

The problem is:

The widget should be updated everytime user clicks on it, showing the current time. And its updating in xamarin Android , but not in the Forms. In xamarin forms, onUpdate method is using only once right after creating the widget, and not calling when user clicks on it.

```
 [BroadcastReceiver(Label = "WIIDget")]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] {"android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"})]
    [MetaData("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/appwidgetprovider")]
    public class Widget : AppWidgetProvider
    {
        public static string AnnouncmentClick = "AnnouncementClickTag";

        public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
        {
            var me = new ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(Widget)).Name);
            appWidgetManager.UpdateAppWidget(me, BuildRemoteViews(context, appWidgetIds));
        }

        private RemoteViews BuildRemoteViews(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)
        {
            var widgetView = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.Widget);
            widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetMedium, "I am a title");
            widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetSmall, $"Last click in {DateTime.Now}");

            var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(Widget));
            intent.SetAction(AppWidgetManager.ActionAppwidgetUpdate);
            intent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId, appWidgetIds);

            var piBackground = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            widgetView.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.widgetBackground, piBackground);

            return widgetView;
        }
    }
```

P.S this impementation is working in xamarin forms, and I can see the time when I open the widget. but the time is not updating when I click on it, as it does in xamarin android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The widget should be updated everytime user clicks on it, showing the current time.

The reason is that when you click your `widget`, your `widget` class cant receive the click event, it didn't know when to update the time.

When you click on your `Widget`, it will send a `broadcast`, you could override the `OnReceive` in your `Widget` to get this message, in `OnReceive` method, you could update the `Widget`, showing the current time. Code like this :

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.Action.Equals("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"))
    {
        var widgetView = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.Widget);
        widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetMedium, "I am a title");
        widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetSmall, $"Last click in {DateTime.Now}");

        var piBackground = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        widgetView.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.widgetBackground, piBackground);

        AppWidgetManager manger = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(context);
        ComponentName thisName = new ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(Widget)).Name);
        manger.UpdateAppWidget(thisName, widgetView);
    }
}
```

I write in Xamarin.Forms project, effect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujw10.gif).